# Ajax database extract - hide load more when all items loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am retrieving data from a mysql database, 5 items each time.

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM names WHERE id < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
$query->execute([$_POST["id"]]);
while($row = $query -> fetch()) {
    echo "<div id="$row["id"].">".$row["name"]."</div>";
});
```

The following javascript is retrieving data from/via the above mysql query. I am passing through the last id of each div and the sql is just taking ones with smaller/older ids to append them below.

```
function request(id) {
    var data1 = "id=" + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://example.com/api",
        data: data1,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
            $(".div").append(html);
        },
        error: function(XHR){
        }
    });
};

request();

$(document).on("click",".more",function(){
    var id = $(".div").children( ":last" ).attr("id");
    request(id);
});
```

Is there a clean way to flag the last result within the php loop so i can pick it up with javascript/jquery and hide the load ".more" button?

Comment: You can first store the total amount of results on the client-side and have a counter variable initialized to 0. With each retrieval, add 5 to the counter variable. When the counter variable becomes equal to the total count, you can hide the load more button.

Comment: The while loop is only populating the .div container with items. It would mess it up if I add any other counters. The only way to pass that from mysql/php to client-side would be with a separate ajax call and not a big fan of this.

Comment: You forget about session variables... Or you could simply check if the query returned less than 5 rows. If it did, then you are at the end of the table.

Comment: This approach would not work if the count of rows is in multiples of 5.

Comment: @Khalil yes, it would as in this case the count of rows for the last query will be 0, which is less than 5

Comment: @Shadow, if for instance you have 10 rows, and you make two AJAX requests and get these 10 rows. The load more button is still being shown although more rows do not exist. Now when the load more button is clicked, no new data is being shown to the user.

Comment: @Khalil correct. Any problem with this?

Comment: Yes, ideally it should also disappear even when 10 rows loaded are everything there is in the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply next steps:

- get the **count of rows** in the `names` table and store it in `hidden input`

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) C FROM names"); 
...
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $row['C'] ?>" id="table_rows_count" />
```

- create additional `hidden input` for **counter value**

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="counter" />
```

- create `hidden div` *container* and store new items in it

```
<div style="display:none;" id="hidden_div"></div>
```

- get `length of children` in the hidden container
- `update counter` value
- `compare` **count of rows** and **children length** and if they are equal then hide the `.more` button
- **clear hidden div** container

```
...
        success: function(html) {
            $(".div").append(html);
            
            $("#hidden_div").append(html);

            var len = $("#hidden_div")[0].children.length, 
                coun = $('#counter').val(), 
                new_counter = coun + len, 
                table_rows = $('#table_rows_count').val();

            $('#counter').val(new_counter);

            if (table_rows == new_counter) $('.more').css('display','none');

            $("#hidden_div").html('')
        },
...
```

*Note: the output of your $.ajax() request has to be present only as a list of divs tags (`<div>...</div>`), nothing else.*
Also, you've forgot to pass an argument into your first-call function `request()`.